# Не понятна разница между 2D массивом определенным **, *[] и [][]

Tags: c, массивы, 2d

Просто сброшу краткий абзац кода, понятнее будет чем словами:

```
int main()
{
int n;
int i;
char *p;
char names[N][M-1];
scanf(«%d», &n);

for (i=0; i<n; i++)
scanf(«%s», names[i]);

/**********************************************/
****/* NEED TO DEFINE AND INITIALIZE HERE names_p */****
/**********************************************/

p = (char *) get_all_names(names_p, n);

{

if (p != NULL)
{
printf(p);
free(p);
}

return 0;
}
char *get_all_names(char *names[], int n)
```

Нужно передать names в `get_all_names` с помощью `names_p`, который собственно и нужно определить как читаемый адресс names для передаваемой функции.

Не понимаю как определить `names_p`, чтобы функция `get_all_names` восприняла его, не смотря на то, что ее первый аргумент типа *[], (а сам names типа [][]).

На данном примере буду рад краткому пояснению разницы между этими типами и здесь необходимыми кастингами.

P.S — работаю в си версии 99, но желательно чтобы работало и на 89.

Условие задания: нельзя ничего менять, нужно только выполнить написанный на английском комментарий (определить и инитиализировать  в конкретной строчке)

Comment: @klopp - Ну зачем вы так?  Двумерные массивы в Си - вещь запутанная.  Иногда двумерный массив создаётся как "сквозной" одномерный (пробегающий все строки матрицы подряд), а иногда - как массив указателей на одномерные массивы.  И потом один к другому не приведёшь обычным кастом.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что это тривиальное учебное задание с искусственным ограничением

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А вообще лучше эмулировать двумерность, создавая одномерный массив размера NxN, а [i][j] элемент будет здесь [(i * N) + j]

Comment: Во-первых, в данном случае вся суть задания заключается именно в том, чтобы совместить изначально физически разные интерфейсы. Т.е. интерфейсные спецификации спускаются вам "свыше" и обсуждению не подлежат. Во-вторых, лучше это или не лучше зависит от специфики приложения. "Рваные массивы" занимают свою нишу. Эмуляция через одномерные - свою.

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно создать "индексный" массив из указателей, требуемый функцией `get_all_names`

```
char *names_p[N];
...

for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
  names_p[i] = names[i];

p = get_all_names(names_p, n);
```

Все.

Какое "пояснение разницы" вы желаете получить, не совсем ясно. Трактаты писать не хочу (читайте литературу), поэтому буду краток.

1. `[][]` - это классический "встроенный" двумерный массив языка С, т.е. плоский массив массивов. В памяти представляется как плоский непрерывный блок, чей размер равен произведению двух указанных размеров.
2. `*[]` - это массив указателей. Так как адресная арифметика языка С позволяет рассматривать указатель, как указатель на начало некоего массива, такая структура данных может выступать в качестве альтернативной реализации двумерного массива. Ответственность за инициализацию указателей возлагается на вас. Внешне синтаксис работы с таким массивом совпадает с `[][]`, но внутреннее устройство такого массива принципиально отличается от 1 и не совместимо с 1.

   Такой способ представления двумерного массива - массив указателей на подмассивы - известен под именем "рваный массив" ("jagged array" или "ragged array").
3. `**` - указатель на указатель. Опять же, в силу тех же причин, такой указатель на указатель может использоваться для реализации двумерного массива. Опять же синтаксис работы с таким массивом совпадает с `[][]`, но внутреннее устройство такого массива принципиально отличается от 1 и не совместимо с 1.

Вот именно из-за несовместимости 1 и 2 вам и надо написать дополнительный код, который сконвертирует ваше `names` (тип 1) в `names_p` (тип 2).

---

P.S. Кстати, в честь чего это у вас написано приведение типа результата `get_all_names` к типу `(char *)` если `get_all_names` и так возвращает `char *`? Я подозреваю, что вы вызываете необъявленную функцию `get_all_names` и, чтобы подавить предупреждение от компилятора, решили поставить там приведение типа? За такое - сразу расстрел. Поэтому ни о каком "нельзя ничего менять" не может быть и речи. Либо переносите определение `get_all_names` наверх, либо добавляйте наверху объявление `get_all_names`.